# What should I do with my XPages Debug Toolbar once I go into production?

Tags: xpages

This might seem stupid, but I'm about to release an XPage application where I've been using the XPage Debug Toolbar (thankyou Mark, should be my daily mantra).

The only way I've thought of doing this is deleting the entry from my 'layout' Custom Control. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do that. What I do is to set up some criteria for when it should be shown. Either some config-setting, a special role - or even checking for the user being you ;-)

This way you can leave it there for later troubleshooting... - which always turns up.

/John

Comment: That's what I do too: setting the loaded property based on an extra role.

Answer (score 1):

Add a little code to determine if it's a development server to the rendering property.  Return false if it's not a dev server.  That's what we do.

Comment: Your answer was good as well david, but John was first and has less points!

Comment: Hey, thanks! Bowing to one of the masters... (David)

Comment: haha.  John does have a very good point.  you could leave it in but only render based on a sessionScope variable...  and then have an admin.xsp page to turn it on when needed.

Comment: Exactly! That way you can easy troubleshoot in production :-)

Comment: This answer is different than John's - this restricts toolbar to dev environment. Most of the SERIOUS problems are in production...